# Method for setting the value of any public field

Tags: c#, reflection

Trying to implement a method that sets the value of any field and does some other stuff.

```
public void SetValue(string fieldName, object value)
{
    GetType().GetField(fieldName).SetValue(this, value);

    // some other stuff
}

... example:

SetValue("SomeFloatField", 10.0f);
```

Is there a way to implement this so I don't have to pass the name of the field as a string? I'm trying to simplify it so you can write something like:

```
SetValue(someFloatField, 10.0f);
SetValue(someObject, new SomeArbitraryObject());
```

Comment: Why not just do an assignment at that point?

Comment: Because of "some other stuff" :), details not really relevant but doing some change tracking and a field binding system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an expression.

```
SetValue(c => c.SomeFloatField, 10.0f);
```

You could accomplish this

```
private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> PropertyExpression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpr;
    switch (PropertyExpression.Body.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            memberExpr = (MemberExpression)PropertyExpression.Body;
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Convert:
            memberExpr = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)PropertyExpression.Body).Operand;
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpr.Member;
    return property;
}

public void SetValue<TOut>(Expression<Func<ThisType, TOut>> PropertyExpression, TOut Value)
{
    PropertyInfo info = GetPropertyInfo<TIn, TOut>(PropertyExpression);

    info.SetValue(this, Value, null);
}
```

Although in that second method, you'd probably be good to make it `static` and use a similar `TIn` pattern instead of stating the type directly. If that wouldn't be necessary, I'm not sure what the purpose of any of this is. It seems like you're trying to circumvent assignment, which seems weird. But if you did make that generic, it'd make a bit more sense.

Comment: @Dmitry That was purposeful. As I said in the paragraph below, that's probably a more useful approach, but the original question asked about setting values on `this`. If it took a `TIn`, we'd need to accept an instance of that to set the value on. I chose `ThisType` arbitrarily because we weren't aware of the type of `this`.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up with:
    public void SetValue<TField>(Expression<Func<TField>> field, object value)
    {
        ((field.Body as MemberExpression).Member as FieldInfo).SetValue(this, value);
    }